# Find out play! version number (e.g. 2.1.3) in application code

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Does anyone know how to find out which version of *play!* an application is running with during runtime? I thought there might perhaps be something like *play.api.Play.current.frameworkVersion*.
I searched the API doc at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/index.html#package for anything useful, but could not find anything.
I think I probably could hack together something like writing the SBT plugin version into a file during the compile/stage which I can then read at runtime. But I was hoping there would be a less cumbersome way of doing this...

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
play.core.PlayVersion.current();
```

found in: [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.2.0-M2/scala/index.html#play.core.PlayVersion$](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.2.0-M2/scala/index.html#play.core.PlayVersion%24)

Comment: Aye, caramba! Thanks Kris, this is exactly what I was looking for. Apparently, this has been added in version 2.2.0-M1, which is why I could not find it in the 2.1.x API doc ^^
So it seems like I'll be doing an upgrade sometime soon...

Comment: @alexander.biskop we're using that in Play 2.0.6, so it's in there it may just not be documented

Comment: Ah, it workse :-) Indeed, it's there; just not documented. Thanks estmatic!